# Is TMutex re-entrant in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, mutex, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm creating my mutex:

```
 FMutex := TMutex.Create(nil, False, 'SomeDumbText');
```

and use it in a method which calls another method using the same created mutex:

```
procedure a;
begin
  FMutex.Acquire;
  try
    //do some work here and maybe call b
  finally
    FMutex.Release;
  end;
end;

procedure b;
begin
  FMutex.Acquire;
  try
    //do some work here
  finally
    FMutex.Release;
  end;
end;
```

It is safe to have nested mutex?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`TMutex` is implemented over the underlying platform object. On Windows that is the mutex object. On the other platforms that is the pthread mutex.

Your question is whether or not `TMutex` is re-entrant. In turn, the answer depends on whether or not the underlying platform object is re-entrant. The Windows mutex is always re-entrant, the pthread mutex is optionally re-entrant, and the Delphi `TMutex` code chooses to use it in re-entrant mode, by calling `pthread_mutexattr_settype(Attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE)`.

So, the answer to your question is that `TMutex` is re-entrant.